# IOS app for pt_BR localization not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localization

I am using Xcode 6 and iOS 8.1 deployment target. I added a localization for Portuguese from Brazil (pt_BR), xcode generated the localized file for storyboard and I translated all the strings. Even so, all the text is displayed in English. I've been fighting for days with these, but I still can not figure out why it does not work.
Obs.: Other localizations, like French and German works, but not Portuguese from Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, iOS8 is using 'pt' for Portuguese Brasil (instead of pt_BR).

but, any way u can use following code for changing language.

```
  if(IS_OS_9_BEFORE) {
    if ([preferredLanguage isEqualToString:@"pt"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pt-BR", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

but, you should have to relaunch your application to effect these changes.
thanks!